# Mayavi get depth map?

Tags: mayavi

I am plotting some stuff with `mayavi.mlab`.  [Here's a basic example](https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/example_exploring_a_vector_field.html) we can work with:

```
from mayavi import mlab
import numpy as np

def V(x, y, z):
    """ A 3D sinusoidal lattice with a parabolic confinement. """
    return np.cos(10*x) + np.cos(10*y) + np.cos(10*z) + 2*(x**2 + y**2 + z**2)
X, Y, Z = np.mgrid[-2:2:100j, -2:2:100j, -2:2:100j
```

I render and save this thing from a particular POV:

```
mlab.options.offscreen = True
mlab.contour3d(X, Y, Z, V)
mlab.savefig("foo.png")
```

I would like to obtain a depth map from the POV that mayavi is rendering this thing.  Presumably, this information or something like it is already computed as part of the rendering.  How do I obtain the depth map for my figure?

Comment: Don't you just need to calculate the distance of every grid point relative to a specific point/line/surface and then color your objects based on that distance?

Comment: I could accomplish such a task, yes.  However, it's not clear in the above example exactly what point I should be doing that with repect to. What are the xyz coordinates of the POV?

Comment: https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/mlab_camera.html `mlab.view()`?